# Uvicorn run on specified python version

Tags: python, uvicorn

When I run

`/home/xxx/.local/bin/uvicorn --version`

I got:

`Running uvicorn 0.17.0 with CPython 3.6.9 on Linux`

But I have installed python3.7, I want to run uvicorn with 3.7 instead 3.6.9.

I have also:

```
/usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

How to point Python to 3.7 instead 3.6 for the uvicorn?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. You can force uvicorn to pick the python  version by giving full command

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

or

```
python3 -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the pip instance associated with your python 3.7 installation and use it instead. You can use `whereis pip` to locate all of the occurrences on your path.

Comment: Not helplul 

`$~/speedtest/py$ whereis pip
pip: /home/xxx/.local/bin/pip3.7 /home/xxx/.local/bin/pip /home/xxx/.local/bin/pip3.10
$ /home/xxx/.local/bin/pip3.10 --version
pip 22.3 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`